# Chrome Extensions Manifest Images

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
     "browser_action": {
       "icons": {
        "16": "rsz_icon.png",
        "48":"rsz_1icon48.png",
        "128":"icon.png"
        }, 
       }
```

These are the icons, yet when I downloaded the extension I still get the Puzzle Piece can anyone explain to me why this is?

Comment: where you see the puzzle piece?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about the puzzle piece displayed in the address bar?
If so you should set the icon in browser_action section.

```
"browser_action": {
   "default_icon": {                    // optional
     "19": "images/icon19.png",           // optional
     "38": "images/icon38.png"            // optional
   },
   "default_title": "Google Mail",      // optional; shown in tooltip
   "default_popup": "popup.html"        // optional
}
```

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html

Comment: Sorry, it is like that. And yes I mean in the address bar

Comment: Can you change it as given above and check whether its working?

Comment: I hope you have put the images in 'images' folder

Comment: why would that matter? I kept the images out of folders, yes it is cleaner to add folders, though it actually adds weight

Comment: It doesn't matter actually if you give it "19": "icon19.png"

Comment: try removing the extension and adding it again

Comment: Please share what you did, it will be useful to others.

Comment: Just was an issue with the browser_action section. Missed the placement. You were correct.